# Predicting return renters

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am trying to figure out an approach for calculating the probability of a renter making > 1 booking. I would prefer to use Python for this project. I have the following columns ready:
State, Category (fun, adventure, etc.), returning_renter? (TRUE if >= 1 booking).

What would be the most efficient approach for this project? Are there any particular Python libraries you would recommend?

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! I'm not sure what your "state" contains (location or condition?), but it sounds like logistic regression is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could trivially prototype your solution in [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si) (it's a Python library that uses [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) under the hood). It also has a neat GUI.

But with only two features (`state` and `renting_reason`), I'm afraid your models might not be as precise as you'd want them to be, unless you have lots of examples to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" approach, when using python, would be data manipulation with the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) library. If you have more complext needs [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library is also a very good idea.

In order to train a predictive model I would highly recommend [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/). It offers a wide range of machine learning algorithms and they have a very good online documentation and examples.

Depending on your needs there may be more efficient approaches but as a rule of a thumb your implementation using the aforementioned libraries will be good enough.

If you are not dealing with a big dataset I would suggest using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) in order to save intermediate python objects instead of having to recalculate them again.